# SQL: percentage deviation from average

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table

```
student class score
--------------------
A        1       6
B        1       5
C        2       6
```

I would like to compute in SQL the score percentage deviation of each class from the average of scores in all classes; in other words

```
(avg_score_in_one_class- avg_score_all_classes)/avg_score_all_classes *100
```

I have computed it with SQL using this query

```
SELECT 
class, 
(AVG(score) - (SELECT AVG(score) FROM table))
/
(SELECT AVG(score) FROM table)
*100
FROM table
GROUP BY class
```

The result should be

```
class deviation
---------------
1      -2.9411764705882404
2      5.882352941176465
```

Is there a way to write it better? For instance, I was thinking of the case in which you have many score columns.

Following the suggestion by Gordon Linoff, I have found a partial solution:

```
WITH temp_table as 
(
    SELECT
        class,
    AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION by class) as avg_class,
    AVG(score) OVER () as avg_score
    FROM table
)

SELECT
    class,
AVG((avg_class-avg_score)/avg_score*100.0) as dev
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY class;
```

which is still not straightforward to be generalised to multiple score columns.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
select class, avg(score) as class_avg,
       (avg(score) * 100.0 / ( sum(sum(score)) over () / sum(count(*)) over () )) - 100.0 as deviation_from_overall_average
from t
group by class;
```

The window expressions are:

- `sum(sum(score)) over ()` calculates the overall sum of the scores.
- `sum(count(*)) over ()` calculates the number of rows in the original data.

The ratio is the overall average.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=72331889edd0652f020d9287a844c756) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your answer it's interesting but it doesn't seem to give the right solution. Please check the updated question

Comment: Show the results you want.

Comment: @Galuoises . . . It produces exactly the same results as the query in your question.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, your result seems to be correct